# how to track CMA allocation on Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, dma

I constantly get `alloc_contig_range: [x, x) PFNs busy` messages in `dmesg`.As I searched it is related to the Linux CMA framework, so I want to know which driver or process caused this problem.in other words I want to know who calls [cma_alloc](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/source/include/linux/cma.h#L29) function or how much cma a process uses.

I also increased my CMA size but that process or drive uses the whole of it every time I increase that